# parse json from GET nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am getting this though an ajax call

```
{ '0': '{"field":"doc_no","cond":"is","val":"","main_cond":"and"}',
  '1': '{"field":"doc_no","cond":"is","val":"","main_cond":"and"}' }
```

I want to convert it to json object, but I couldn't make anything out of it.

trying to use JSON.parse, but something is missing.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: this is not a valid JSON. JSON allows double quotes only as property name / value wrapper

Comment: I am getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 2

Answer (score 0):

If the object looks like this, you can do some further parsing:

```js
let obj = { '0': '{"field":"doc_no","cond":"is","val":"","main_cond":"and"}',
  '1': '{"field":"doc_no","cond":"is","val":"","main_cond":"and"}' };
  
for(let p in obj) {
    obj[p] = JSON.parse(obj[p]);
}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{ '0': '{"field":"doc_no","cond":"is","val":"","main_cond":"and"}',
  '1': '{"field":"doc_no","cond":"is","val":"","main_cond":"and"}' }
```

This is not valid JSON string. Correct would be, for example:

```js
var parseMe = ' { "0": { "field": "doc_no", "cond": "is", "val": "", "main_cond": "and" },"1":{"field": "doc_no","cond": "is", "val": "", "main_cond": "and" }}';
console.log(JSON.parse(parseMe));
```